# How to access site from Private Container Apps accessed via VPN gateway - Azure

Tags: azure, azure-vpn, azure-container-apps

I created a private container apps where I would like to access its web site via vpn gateway.

The private container apps is into the VNET, specific of RG where contains a NSG (default configuration). Also, I created and configured the private DNS zone in which I create a Virtual Network Link associated to VNET, than I added a record set with name *.[same container app address] and container app ip address.

I have a VPN already configured for other VMs and is working. It is into another RG (hub) with its VNET and NSG. I configured peering between hub vnet and spoke vnet.

So, I can't access the web site via vpn. The host not found. I don't have an idea to resolve it. Maybe there is additional configuration in the NSG where the docker container is running in the 9000:9000.

That's the overview print the infrastructure.

[image]

Does anyone have any idea what I may do?

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same issue in my environment and got the below results***

*I have created the vnet with two subnets ,one for container app and another for vnet*

[image]

*We can find in below image*

[image]

*I have created the container app*

[image]

*If we want to access the app we have only static IP, using static IP we cannot access the application, so that  have created the private DNS zone*

[image]

*Integrated the virtual network with DNS zone*

[image]

*I have added the record set using static IP to access the application*

[image]

*I have completed the peering between hub and spoke vnets*

[image]

*After that I have added the route tables to connect the host
for both spoke1 and spoke2*

*I have added the routes for both the networks*

[image]

*I have routed the subnet for spoke1 to route1
same for spoke 2 - route2 also*

[image]

*When I open the network configurations  I am able to see the vpn gate way got created*

[image]

*When I ping the vpn gateway subnet I am able get*

[image]